# iOS Swift - print from Set to Label

Tags: ios, swift, set, uilabel

I have a Set like this:

```
var favoriteGenres: Set<String> = ["Rock", "Classical", "Hip hop"]
```

And I want to print it to a text Label.
When I use:

```
myLabel.text = “\(favoriteGenres)”
```

I get:

> ["Rock", "Classical", "Hip hop"]

But instead I want it to be:

> Rock
>
> Classical
>
> Hip hop

How can this be done?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at the `joined(separator:)` function of `Set`?

Comment: While the duplicate refers to Array, it works with Set too.

Comment: Note that Swift sets are unordered, so the order you get out of this is undefined. A solution to that would be to initialize an array from the set, sort it into the desired order, and then use `joined(separator:)`